# Real time test reported in Jenkins for TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, jenkins-plugins

Is there any Real time Test Reporter to view the test results during the execution in Jenkins. Am using Maven + TestNG framework to execute the test cases.

Comment: Most of the reporting tools give you the results after execution is done. What you can do is adding log4j into all your steps and this way you can see all the steps and even log your test results to see that while jenkins is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the Runtime Reporter that was built as part of [SeLion](http://selion.io), an automation framework from PayPal.

To add this, you would need to add the below as a maven dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.selion</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeLion</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

RuntimeReporter is basically wired in as a service loaded reporter, so it should start the moment your TestNG tests kick off.

Class name of interest : `com.paypal.selion.internal.reports.runtimereport.RuntimeReporterListener`

You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/paypal/SeLion/blob/develop/client/src/main/java/com/paypal/selion/internal/reports/runtimereport/RuntimeReporterListener.java) on github.